# Getting the minor element of a list

Tags: r

How to get the minor and the second minor element of a list? Are there some function that does it?

Example:

```
a <- c(3,2,1)
minor(a)
1
sminor(a)
2
```

Comment: What do you want returned when `a <- c(3,1,1)`?

Comment: The more typical term for this is teh minimum rather than the `minor`. The term `minor` is used in discussion certain matrix operations, so it's use here seemed incongruous. The inbuilt function is `min`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using `sort`?

```
# slightly less confusing test values
x <- c(2,7,5)

# get the second smallest value
sort(x)[2]
[1] 5
```

Or to get the index of the second smallest number instead of the value, use `order`:

```
order(x)[2]
[1] 3
```

...where you could return the value with

```
x[order(x)[2]]
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Minimum value?

```
> min(a)
[1] 1
```

And the runner-up:

```
> min(a[a!=min(a)])
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want slightly different behaviour (in case of repeated values):

```
min(a)

min(a[-which.min(a)])
```